# How can you check to see if a card number starts with a prefix that belongs to a set of predefined prefixes using C#?

Tags: c#, validation

I have a range of card number prefixes of various lengths e.g. `11220-11221`, `6337461000000000-6337468549999999`, `945-965`.

How can I check to see if a card number (16 character string) e.g. `6337468549960326` starts with a defined prefix?

I thought I could try to add all the possible prefix values between the start and end values to some kind of list and then check if the card number begins with one of the possible prefixes however obviously the prefix list could be very large!

With the code I created using a similar logic, I get an out of memory exception when adding to my list `_prefixes`.

```
private string _ranges = "11220, 11221; 6337461000000000, 6337468549999999; 945, 965;"
private HashSet<string>() _prefixes;

public bool IsCardNumberValid(string cardNumber)
{
    this.PopulatePrefixes();
    
    return this._prefixes.Any(x => cardNumber.StartsWith(x));
}

private void PopulatePrefixes()
{
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(this._ranges))
    {
        return;
    }

    string[] array2 = rangeString.Split(';');
    for (int i = 0; i < array2.Length; i++)
    {
        string[] array3 = array2[i].Split(',');
        if (array3.Length == 2)
        {
            var minRange = Convert.ToInt64(array3[0]);
            var maxRange = Convert.ToInt64(array3[1]);

            lock (this.rangeLock)
            {
                this._prefixes = new HashSet<string>();

                for (var x = minRange; x <= maxRange; x++)
                {
                    this._prefixes.Add(x.ToString());
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are we talking lexically or numerically? You need to choose one of them.

Comment: @Fildor What's the difference?

Comment: Generating every single number in a big range is a big waste of space. Since your credit card numbers are already strings, you can build a [Trie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) and index them by each character. Then you only need to store the prefixes themselves, not entire ranges of numbers with that prefix.

Comment: That card number can only contain digits, no characters?

Comment: @Evk That's correct, only digits.

Comment: _"What's the difference"_ - meanwhile the difference is gone :) Usually it's a difference if a string has Prefix "abc" or a number is LowerBound < X < UpperBound ...

Comment: Like this maybe: https://dotnetfiddle.net/Jq5hnB ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since card number contains only digits, and is of fixed size (16 characters) you can pad your lower bound prefix with 0s to the right up to 16 characters, and pad upper bound prefix with 9s to the right up to 16 characters, and then do numeric comparision (we assume that both lower and higher bound prefixes are inclusive). For example, "945-965" prefix means your card number is >= than 9450000000000000 and <= than 9659999999999999. Sample code:

```
private string _rangesRaw = "11220, 11221; 6337461000000000, 6337468549999999; 945, 965;";
private List<Range> _prefixes = new List<Range>();

public bool IsCardNumberValid(string cardNumber) {
    this.PopulatePrefixes();
    var cardNumberAsLong = long.Parse(cardNumber);
    return this._prefixes.Any(x => cardNumberAsLong >= x.Min && cardNumberAsLong <= x.Max);
}

private void PopulatePrefixes() {        
    foreach (var range in _rangesRaw.Split(";")) {
        if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(range))
            continue;
        var min = range.Split(",")[0].Trim();
        if (min.Length < 16)
            min = min + new string('0', 16 - min.Length);
        var max = range.Split(",")[1].Trim();
        if (max.Length < 16)
            max = max + new string('9', 16 - max.Length);
        _prefixes.Add(new Range(long.Parse(min), long.Parse(max)));
    }
}

class Range {
    public Range(long min, long max) {
        // probably want to throw here if min > max
        Min = min;
        Max = max;
    }

    public long Min {get;}
    public long Max{get;}
}
```

Comment: I was just wondering about the upper bound: Is it _really_ correct to pad with "0", shouldn't it be "9"? (Only _upper_ bound.) Probably depends if the upper bound should be inclusive or exclusive ...

Comment: Yes probably depends on that. But sample data has for example `11220 - 11221` which for me suggests upper bound is inclusive (though only OP knows for sure)

Comment: So, if 11221 is an included _prefix_ , then "1122101234567890" should be valid, no? The first *in*valid one should be "1122200000000000" ... I'm overthinking again. Details ... :D

Comment: Ah I see what you mean. Yes you are right, I've updated the answer.

Comment: Yes, the upper prefix is also valid e.g. if a card started with 11221, 6337468549999999 or 965, they would be valid.

Answer (score 0):

i would check if the prefix of the card number falls into one of the ranges.
here is a small example for doing so:

```
  public class CardTrouble
    {
        private static string _ranges = "11220, 11221; 6337461000000000, 6337468549999999; 945, 965; 5, 1000;";
        private static List<PrefixRange> _prefixRanges = new List<PrefixRange>();

        public static void DoCardTrouble()
        {
            PopulatePrefixRanges();
            IsCardNumberValid("11219");
        }

        public static bool IsCardNumberValid(string cardNumber)
        {
            foreach(var range in _prefixRanges)
            {
                var minLength = range.Min.ToString().Length;
                var maxLength = range.Max.ToString().Length;
                if (minLength <= cardNumber.Length && cardNumber.Length <= maxLength)
                {
                    var pCardNumber = long.Parse(cardNumber.Substring(0, range.Max.ToString().Length));
                    if (range.Min <= pCardNumber && pCardNumber <= range.Max)
                    {
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }
            return false;
        }

        private static void PopulatePrefixRanges()
        {
            var sRanges = _ranges.Split(";");
            foreach(var sRange in sRanges)
            {
                if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(sRange))
                {
                    var prefixRange = new PrefixRange();
                    prefixRange.Min = long.Parse(sRange.Split(",")[0]);
                    prefixRange.Max = long.Parse(sRange.Split(",")[1]);
                    _prefixRanges.Add(prefixRange);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public class PrefixRange
    {
        public long Min { get; set; }
        public long Max { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: I think you may want to switch `return false;` and `return true;` in `IsCardNumberValid()`?

Comment: thanks for the hint! i thought the task was to return true if the card number doesnt start with one of the prefixes ^^

Answer (score 0):

I think it doesn't need to convert prefix ranges to be numerical ranges. Here is sample code that could work with alphanumeric ranges.

```
private string string _ranges = "11220, 11221; 6337461000000000, 6337468549999999; 945, 965;";
private string List<string[]> _listRanges = null;   

public bool IsCardNumberValid(string cardNumber)
{
    if (this._listRanges == null)  
        this._listRanges = this.PopulatePrefixes(this._ranges);

    return this._listRanges.Any(range => range[0].CompareTo(cardNumber) <= 0 
                    && range[1].CompareTo(cardNumber) >= 0);
}

private string List<string[]> PopulatePrefixes(string inputRanges)
{
    var listRanges = new List<string[]>();
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(inputRanges))
    {
        return listRanges;
    }

    string[] ranges = inputRanges.Split(';');
    foreach(var item in ranges) {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(item)) continue;
        var range = item.Split(',');
        if (range.Length > 0) {
            
            listRanges.Add(new string[2]);
            var index = listRanges.Count - 1;
            
            // add lower bound letter for start of the range
            listRanges[index][0] = range[0].Trim() + "0";
            
            // add upper bound letter for end of the range
            listRanges[index][1] = range.Length > 1 ? range[1].Trim() + "z" : "z";
        }           
    }
    return listRanges;
}
```